# Why excel is not being uploaded throught codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mime-types, codeigniter-form-helper

Hi, I want to upload excel file and after upload, I would like to <strike>insert (file-path)</strike> parse file and insert data into database and an error occures in my controller no matter what mimetype I set it to accept unless wildcard is applied.

error

`(The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.)`

I used some code mentioned in below-

```
$this->_require_admin();
$this->load->library('spreadsheet_excel_reader');
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');

$file_element_name = "excelFile";

$configUpload['upload_path'] = 'insexcel/';
$configUpload['allowed_types'] = 'XLS|text/comma-separated-values|application/csv|application/excel|application/vnd.ms-excel|application/vnd.msexcel|text/anytext|text/plain|text/csv|csv|application/vnd.ms-excel';
$configUpload['max_size'] = '5000';
$configUpload['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $configUpload);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)) {
    $status = 'error';
    echo $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
} else {
    echo "not upload";
}
```

And if i assign `$configUpload['allowed_types'] = '*';` then file is being uploaded successfully. I want check a proper mime type of file.

<strike>How to insert excel data into database?</strike>

How to upload excel file into server and parse it?

Comment: Your last question (`How to insert excel data into database?`) has nothing to do with the rest...

Comment: This is actually good question but low quality, OP is asking two separate things the biggest issue is with uploading file, I know that xls files are really pain in bu** (in content with CodeIgniter), I never solved this issue I simply use wildcard `$configUpload['allowed_types'] = '*';` and it is so unsafe but w/e. After sucessful upload OP should be able to parse file with `spredsheat_excel_library` easily.